# How to install custom SSL (HTTPS) certificate in RSA NetWitness web UI (11.3.1.1)

Tags: rsa

RSA NetWitness's web user interface (11.3.1.1) comes with self-signed cert that isn't trusted in my enterprise. How can I install a custom SSL certificate on the web user interface so that users aren't presented with a certificate error?

I already have the SSL certificate signed by my internal CA and associated key.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the PEM (base64) certificate (`fqdn.cer`) and its private key (`fqdn.key`), here are the steps I used to install the custom SSL (HTTPS) certificate:

1. Open `fqdn.cer` in Windows and export the root certificate as `root.cer` (base64)
2. Open `fqdn.cer` in Windows and export the intermediate certificate as `intermediate.cer` (base64)
3. Concatenate `intermediate.cer` and `root.cer` to create `chain.cer`.
4. Create a p7b file with all certificates:

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile fqdn.cer -certfile chain.cer -out fqdn.p7b
```

5. Convert the RSA key to PKCS#1 (should begin with ----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY---- ):

```
openssl rsa -in "fqdn.key" -out "fqdn.key2"
```

7. Backup existing certs:

```
mkdir /root/default_certs
cp /etc/pki/nw/web/web-server-* /root/default_certs
```

8. Copy (and overwrite) with new certs:

```
cp fqdn.key2 /etc/pki/nw/web/web-server-key.pem
cp fqdn.cer /etc/pki/nw/web/web-server-cert.pem
cp chain.cer /etc/pki/nw/web/web-server-cert.chain
cp fqdn.p7b /etc/pki/nw/web/web-server-cert.p7b
```

9. Restart nginx:

```
service nginx restart
```

References:

- https://community.rsa.com/thread/199013
- https://community.rsa.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadBody/96728-102-3-264225/SecConf.pdf